# Session & PHP & Joomla & Code Optimization

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5.

1st method

```
JFactory::getSession()->set('mymessage', 'here is some message text');
```

2nd method

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('mymessage', 'here is some message text');
```

I use above methods(1 or 2) in my constructor. So I want to optimize the PHP code since it will be called multiple times during execution. What I want to know is which method is effective and efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is un_named session variable call which will avoid `$session` need and initialization apart from that everything is same. therefore first may have some efficiency over space may be in time also.

Answer (score 1):

Do loops 10 loops of 10 000 for each of the methods (1 and 2) and time them with microtime and calculate the average.